# Android App crashes without any Stack Trace Error

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I just started with that new App and wanted to see if I get any Response by Retrofit and print it in a TextView.

But the App crashes without any Stack Trace so no Exception ... just nothing.

I have a Retrofit interface and a "Factory" that creates the Request everything runs in a different Thread via Kotlin Coroutine.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var debugTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        debugTextView = findViewById(R.id.debugTextView)

        val service = RetrofitFactory.makeCarDataService()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val request = service.getData()

            val response = request.await()

            debugTextView.text =response.toString()

        }
    }
}
```

I would love to post an Error ... but there is none, everything should run perfectly :/

Comment: impossible there are no stacktace...

Comment: Just a stack trace of starting the app and the debugger but the app crashes immediately without an error/exception...

Comment: Remove all the code after `debugTextView = findViewById(R.id.debugTextView)`, did it crashed?

Answer (score 4):

To use `Dispatchers.Main` we need to add the following line to the app's **build.gradle** file dependencies:

> implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'

Absence of that dependency could be the reason why the app crashes without any stack trace.

Comment: This worked for me. Remove the $ sign though like this: implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

Without stacktrace these are the possible problems:

```
service.getData()
```

can throw `NullPointerException`

```
debugTextView.text
```

can throw `NullPointerException`

```
response.toString()
```

can throw `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the coroutines, but have you tried to use the main thread only while setting the text on the view? something like this:

```
val service = RetrofitFactory.makeCarDataService()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default/*change here*/) {
        val request = service.getData()

        val response = request.await()
        /*change here*/
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            debugTextView.text = response.toString()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
    val request = service.getData()
    val response = request.await()
    debugTextView.text =response.toString()
} catch (e: RuntimeException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    t.printStackTrace()
}
```